# A string starts with "something" + contains something else

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I check if a string starts with "something" **and** contains some other characters using regex? I can do this that like this:

```
if my_str.start_with?("something") && my_str.size > "something".size
```

How to do the same thing by regex?

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: `/^something.+/` How about trying to learn regex yourself? You could start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I already have shown an example.

Comment: `and contains some other characters using regex?`  What do you mean by some other characters?

Comment: @Biffen, `if my_str =~ '/^\/categories.+/'` =====> error `type mismatch, String given`. The original string to check is "/categories".

Comment: @Grienders I know virtually nothing about Ruby, so I wouldn't know. A wild guess is that the rvalue looks more like a string than a regex (if regex is a primitive type in Ruby). **Edit** A quick search later: Have you got the parameters in the wrong order?

Comment: `'/^\/categories.+/'` is a string, use `/^\/categories.+/`

Comment: BTW, if your regexp contains `/`, you can use the `%r{...}` literal, e.g. `%r{/categories.+}`

Comment: @Stefan, then can't use if it as "=~".

Comment: @Grienders of course you can: `'abc' =~ %r{b} #=> 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/\Asomething.+/`:

```
regexp = /\Asomething.+/
```

`\A` matches the beginning of a string. `.+` matches at least one following character.

```
'something'.match(regexp)
#=> nil

'something else'.match(regexp)
#=> <MatchData "something else">
```

Comment: I haven't heard of A, why not ^?

Comment: @Grienders `^` = beginning of line, `\A` = beginning of string. You can use them interchangeably if your string doesn't contain multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

spickermann's answer is close (it works), but is redundant. This is how to do it with regex:

```
my_str =~ /\Asomething./
```